# Voting to reopen in order to close for a different reason

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Very related to [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/multiple-close-answer-reasons), I think.

If a question is closed for (what you consider to be) an incorrect reason but should anyway be closed for a different reason, should you vote to reopen and (once reopened) then vote to close for a different reason?

Case in point:

[studying for conversion to Conservative online](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93159/studying-for-conversion-to-conservative-online) was originally closed by five users as a duplicate. I voted to reopen it because I did not think it was a duplicate. Three other users voted to reopen and it is now open. However, [one of the comments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93159/studying-for-conversion-to-conservative-online#comment304208_93159) suggested that the question should be closed because it is primarily opinion based (and this comment was there before the question was reopened). Additionally, the question has been flagged as being (close-worthy because it is) not about Judaism.

Does it make sense to vote to close it after just voting to reopen it? On the other hand, I assume we want to be precise and if a question is not a duplicate it shouldn't be labeled as such even if it is otherwise off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

No, if the question should be closed, don't vote to reopen it: that's counterproductive in that it opens the question to answers (at least temporarily, and you may not garner enough reclosure votes). If the closure reason is wrong, you can express your opinion in a comment on the question or in [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468).

Comment: Or a flag. Mods can reopen and close immediately. There's a flag for something that requires moderator attention.

Comment: Perhaps if I can't garner enough reclosure votes that is an indication that it *shouldn't* be reclosed (i.e. the community does not agree with my reason to close)?

Comment: @Alex re your comment: but the community closed the question so thinks it should be closed. I don't think you should worry about the closure reasons too much: if it's closed and should be, that's a good thing.

Comment: There is a concrete reason, though. Questions closed as duplicates don't qualify for automatic deletion of closed questions after 9 days, and dupe closures don't cause migration rejections.

Comment: @gparyani, excellent points. Might I suggest you post an answer here?