# If a question has multiple closeworthy problems with it, what should the close vote be for?

Tags: discussion, policy, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Consider [Very big contradiction between 4 elements in Judaism - Olam Haba](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/103766/1). As I noted in the comments there, the OP asks three different questions (too broad), two of which are duplicates and one is unclear.

What’s the correct procedure for closing here? Is there a “hierarchy” for different close reasons, where if multiple apply one takes precedence over the others? Or does it matter which reason you pick?

In the particular example here I picked “too broad,” as it was the most overarching problem of them all, and I left a comment referring to the others. Was this correct procedure?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/multiple-close-answer-reasons

Answer (score 5):

I recommend closing using any reason that is relevant, with priority going to whichever would be most likely to point the author in the direction of a constructive edit<sup>1</sup>. Then, if you think that the post has many issues that prevent it from being a good fit, I recommend leaving a comment that explains all of the issues and requests correction of them. If we do that, then it doesn't matter as much what the closure reason is; the author and editors should do their best to address concerns raised in the comments to make the post a good fit.

---

<sup>1. Thanks to DoubleAA for this formulation of priority.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I would say that for the most part it doesn't really matter, but I think that in general "Unclear what you're asking" should come first. If we can't understand what is being asked then we presumably (albeit with certain exceptions) can't judge whether it is Too Broad, Primarily Opinion-Based, Off-Topic, or a duplicate.

Comment: In the majority of cases this probably ends up being the same as Isaac's answer